# Update access database with two primary keys

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I am writing a c++ application that connect to a Microsoft Access database through ODBC connection.  When I update a database with a single primary key, I use the following SQL command:

```
UPDATE [MY_TABLE] SET [Type] = ?, [Value] = ?, [Rating] = ? WHERE [Part Number] = ?
```

I now have a need to update a record in a database with two primary keys where the primary keys are Part Number and Revision.  I tried this command

```
UPDATE [MY_TABLE] SET [Type] = ?, [Value] = ?, [Rating] = ?, [Revision] = ? WHERE [Part Number] = ?
```

but it give me error if there's duplicate in the Part Number field.  I also tried

```
UPDATE [MY_TABLE] SET [Type] = ?, [Value] = ?, [Rating] = ? WHERE [Part Number] = ?, [Revision] = ?
```

but it is not a correct format.  How do I setup my command to update a database record with two primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` to instead of `,` in the `WHERE` clause. It's not a list you use there, it's a Boolean expression.

```
UPDATE [MY_TABLE] SET [Type] = ?, [Value] = ?, [Rating] = ? WHERE [Part Number] = ? AND [Revision] = ?
```